# Where are constraints updated for size classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a constraint in interface builder with a default value and a compact width value. I have this constraint linked to an IBOutlet so I can get the constant value in code at runtime. If I run on an iPhone 4S simulator, in `viewDidLoad` the constant is the default value. Neither `willTransitionToTraitCollection` or `viewWillTransitionToSize` get called, but at some point the constraint is updated to the compact value as later on it is correct. Where does the constraint get updated by `UIViewController`? It's not `updateViewConstraints`.

Update: The suggested `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `traitCollectionDidChange` methods are not where the constant is changed either:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    println("Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: \(self.navControllerBottomSpaceConstraint.constant)")
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    println("After viewDidLayoutSubviews: \(self.navControllerBottomSpaceConstraint.constant)")
}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    println("Before traitCollectionDidChange: \(self.navControllerBottomSpaceConstraint.constant)")
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    println("After traitCollectionDidChange: \(self.navControllerBottomSpaceConstraint.constant)")
}
```

Output:

```
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 20.0
Before traitCollectionDidChange: 20.0
After traitCollectionDidChange: 20.0
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 0.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 0.0
Before viewDidLayoutSubviews: 0.0
After viewDidLayoutSubviews: 0.0
```

Comment: what do you actually need to? respond to change or catch the moment when it is changed?

Comment: I need to know what the value is so I can set up my UI around that. I need to do some image processing so can't do it multiple times in viewDidLayoutSubviews. I need to know once when the constraint is at its final value.

Comment: well, the first `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that occur after `viewDidAppear` is the place where the initial layout is done. You do not trace it in `viewDidLoad` since the view hasn't aligned itself properly. I suggest you to set a bool that view appeared and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` check this bool once + remember the constraint value. And after that you can compare it's value to reflect any UI changes.

Comment: Actually, you can make a first step right in `viewDidAppear`, i think

Comment: "I need to know what the value is so I can set up my UI around that" That's a Bad Smell. The point of layout constraints is that _they_ set up the UI. Not criticising, but if you explain more fully what you want to do, I bet we can give a better way to do it.

Comment: I have a view which displays images at the full screen size. I have some user interface views which are displayed on top with a blur background. I know which part of the images I want to display are important, so I make sure that part is not displayed behind the UI elements and stretch the edges of the image to make sure there are no visible gaps even during rotation.

Comment: I therefore use the constraint constants to know how big the UI elements are. I could use the size instead of the constraints now I have been able to determine when it has been laid out, answer to follow. But either way, I wouldn't know what the visible area on the background image view is before everything had been laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Matt and Sega-Zero for pointing me in the right direction.

The answer is the constraint is updated in the view's first `layoutSubviews` after it has entered the view hierarchy. So in your view controller you can do this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if self.propertyCalculatedFromConstraints == nil && self.view.window != nil {
        // constraints and sizes are now valid
        self.propertyCalculatedFromConstraints = self.constraint.constant
    }
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}

override func viewDidDisappear() {
    self.propertyCalculatedFromConstraints = nil
    super.viewDidDisappear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[traitCollectionDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITraitEnvironment/traitCollectionDidChange:) is the place where you can catch size classes change or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the parent view is the place where you can detect any autolayout changes

Comment: It isn't changed in either of those methods, see my updated question. Thanks